# How to restore drive icon on Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, 13.10

I have 2 WINDOWS drive icon on Unity Launcher but I unlock 1 from Unity Launcher. How to restore it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Start **dconf Editor**
2. Go to **com** > **canonical** > **unity** > **devices**
3. Remove your driver specified as **UUID-Label** from the **blacklist**

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file `mimeapps.list` from `/home/USER/.local/share/applications`.

Answer (score 0):

Came here seeking knowledge...

Actually, Google sent me here searching for how to restore a disk icon to my Unity Launcher in Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial).

Problem Summary:  my windows partition /dev/sda8 (Label:  User) did not appear as a disk icon on my Unity Launcher, even though the partition exists, and I could mount it manually to /mnt.  All of the above did not work -- there was *nothing* in the blacklist.

Problem Solution:  It turns out my partition /dev/sda8 was listed in /etc/fstab as the swap partition.  lsblk -f showed that /dev/sda6 had a label of 'swap' and the FSTYPE was 'swap'.  Not sure how this happened.  I edited the /etc/fstab file (sudo vim /etc/fstab) and changed swap to /dev/sda6;  saved the file and exited the editor.  Then in the 'disks' application / GUI I selected the /dev/sda8 partion and then clicked on the small right-facing triangular button below the Volumes partition (on the left).  The partition immediately mounted and an icon was automagically added to the Unity Launcher.

How I figured this out:

output from lsblk (note:  lsblk -f is easier to type)

```
O=(--Excalibur---~$   lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT

NAME   FSTYPE LABEL       MOUNTPOINT

sda                       
├─sda1 ntfs   Data        /media/steve/Data
├─sda2 ntfs   OS          /media/steve/OS
├─sda3                    
├─sda5 ext4               /
├─sda6 swap   swap        
├─sda7 ntfs   Data        /media/steve/Data1
└─sda8 ntfs   User        /media/steve/User
sdb                       
└─sdb1 ntfs   Backup_4TB  /media/steve/Backup_4TB
sr0
```

I was fooling around in the 'disks' GUI (go to the Launcher, type 'disks') and trying to mount /dev/sda8.  When I bothered to actually read the error message,I saw 'swap' mentioned.  That gave me the idea to check /etc/fstab and I saw that /dev/sda8 was set as swap.  No wonder 'disks' could not mount it and it was not showing up on the Unity launcher.

Hope this helps someone.