# How to disable automatic launcher icons for external drives?

Tags: unity, nautilus, launcher, icons, external-hdd

I was wonder if there was a way to disable automatic launcher icons for external drives.  I plug my externals in, and immediately have to close the windows that pop up and remove the icons from the Unity Launcher.  Is there a way to disable this process and to also access my externals from the nautilus icon instead of individual icons for the externals?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/363865/how-to-restore-drive-icon-on-unity-launcher?rq=1

Comment: You aren't the first one to ask this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/761798/how-to-prevent-external-usb-drive-icon-appearing-in-launcher

Comment: @ElderGeek I think I found a dupe, see above --^

Comment: @AndroidDev Looks right to me.